# Changing marker shape to circles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, symbology, markers

I was wondering how to change the default marker shape in a Leaflet map to circles

```
$.ajax("data/StatesPopulation.geojson", {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            L.geoJson(response, {
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(mymap);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Within the L.geoJson function you can call the `pointToLayer` function.

To create circles you can do something like:

```
$.ajax("data/StatesPopulation.geojson", {
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    L.geoJson(response, {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
          radius: 5,
          color: '#FF0000'
        });
      },
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(mymap);
  }
});
```

In [this](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) documentation you can see a more detailed example.

Comment: And If I want to convert my circles to proportional symbols based on the attributes, do I need to write "if" function?

Comment: You can do as in [@IvanSanchez's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243920/99589) with `for`-loop or with [`eachLayer` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#layergroup-eachlayer) like in this article [Time Series Proportional Symbol Maps with Leaflet and jQuery | Example 13](http://www.cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/view/cp76-donohue-et-al/1307) or this thread [How to loop through geojson layers on leaflet map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466274/how-to-loop-through-geojson-layers-on-leaflet-map).

Comment: In this particular case, one could just do something like `radius: feature.properties.foobar * 3,` or whatever.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whats the purpose of `onEachFeature: onEachFeature`?

Comment: Its reference to a function. This is helpful if you would like to bind popups to each feature of the geojson for example.