# Leaflet Circle Rendering as Marker

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markers, circle

I'm trying to create a map with circles of different size radii, to this end I'm trying to use the [Leaflet `circle` class](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#circle). The issue I'm having is that despite specifying `circle` and passing a radius the locations render themselves as the default icon.

Below is the HTML and JavaScript code that I'm using to render the map, the key line being `return L.circle([feature.properties.latitude, feature.properties.longitude], {radius: 20});`

HTML

```html
<style type="text/css">
#map {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="map"></div>
```

JavaScript

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([53.96, -3.22], 5);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery Â© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZW5lcmd5dmlzIiwiYSI6ImNrbjR2aWo4azBsaHEycHM5dHByZzFnZW8ifQ.MyLCIQqHnNHQFWJQqs-j4w'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var geojsonFeature = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'id': '10031', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'fuel_type': 'gas', 'latitude': 51.542919, 'longitude': 0.8349610000000001, 'name': 'Coryton', 'output': 264.64, 'output_time': '2020-01-01 01:30'}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [0.8349610000000001, 51.542919]}}, {'id': '10036', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'fuel_type': 'gas', 'latitude': 51.662337, 'longitude': -0.022763, 'name': 'Enfield Energy', 'output': 232.416, 'output_time': '2020-01-01 01:30'}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-0.022763, 51.662337]}}, {'id': '10045', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'fuel_type': 'gas', 'latitude': 50.903033, 'longitude': -1.351318, 'name': 'Marchwood', 'output': 310.2, 'output_time': '2020-01-01 01:30'}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-1.351318, 50.903033]}}]}

    var geoJson = new L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('<p>Name: '+feature.properties.name);
            return L.circle([feature.properties.latitude, feature.properties.longitude], {radius: 20});
        }
    }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

[image: example leaflet map with markers instead of circles]

I am using Leaflet 1.3.1

Comment: There is also CircleMarker  as shown here -https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313702/changing-marker-shape-to-circles-in-leaflet

Answer (score 1):

I still can't understand why the previous code doesn't work but using an alternative approach with `pointToLayer` and `L.Circle` seems to achieve the desired effect.

```js
var geoJson = new L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
        return new L.Circle([feature.properties.latitude, feature.properties.longitude], feature.properties.output*50);
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('<p>Name: '+feature.properties.name);
    }
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Read description of `pointToLayer` and `onEachFeature` options in docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson